# MYSQL Query to extract to value only

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to write a **mysql** query that selects the final result in the figure below :

[image: Figure 1]

Thanks

Any solution, for this question.

Comment: Standard "first/last row in a group".

Comment: How can do that  ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use order by and limit

Comment: @SelVazi , I want to select only two rows the conditions are :
1. First row is the maximum **Key** when **ID DEVICE** is 1.
2. Second row is the maximum **Key** when **ID DEVICE** is 2.

But I can't use Limit!!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, Execute query as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets 
GROUP BY device_id 
HAVING key_field = MAX(key_field) 
ORDER BY device_id ASC
```

Will produce result as you expected:

| Key | ID device | ticket Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 212 | 1 | 594 |
| 211 | 2 | 147 |

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. It's an invalid grouping query, but even if one disables ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, it produces an empty result. Cf. https://dbfiddle.uk/kzZw3DZJ

Comment: @BillKarwin This query has been executed in `sqlite`

Comment: The OP asked for a solution in MySQL.